# How to select a file from documents & media library in custom porltet Liferay - 7

Tags: module, document-library, liferay-7

Can anyone help me how can i open a popup for selecting a file form documents and media?

I am using Liferay DXP

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : create document library URL in your jsp

Answer (score 0):

Step 2: Create a div or html content
documentLibraryInput"id="documentLibraryInput" />article-image" src=""style="width:82px;height:83px" vspace="0" />showImages()" >Select a thumbnail image